# How to use debuginfo rpms

Tags: c++, remote-debugging, debug-information

I have a debuginfo rpm ([link](https://www.monshouwer.eu/download/3rd_party/pdns/el6/x86_64/debuginfo/)) (pdns-debuginfo-3.4.1-1.el6.MIND.x86_64.rpm) and
I want to remote debug pdns.

I have installed gdb gdbserver on my Linux box. How can I remote debug pdns using `debuginfo`?